# Restful way for deleting all items

Tags: rest, api-design

I am designing an API for domain admin to manage user cookie sessions, specifically

`GET users/{userKey}/sessions` to get a list of a user's all sessions
`DELETE users/{userKey}/sessions/{sessionId}` to delete a user's specific session

I want to expose another method for the admin to delete (reset) a user's all sessions. I am considering 2 options, I wonder which one is more Restful

1. `DELETE users/{userKey}/sessions` - {sessionId} left blank to delete all sessions
2. `POST users/{userKey}/sessions/reset`

Answer (score 1):

REST was never designed for bulk transaction support, it's for representing the state of individual objects.  That said, API design is very opinionated and you have to balance REST "pureness" with functionality.  If I were designing this, I would go with option 1 and use delete at the "sessions" endpoint since you are removing all of the user sessions and not just a single or subset.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be opinion based, so take it as such. 
I would use **DELETE** if you are **removing** the resource (since you are going to be removing sessions).

If you keep the sessions (but change some data in those resources eg sliding expiration) then I would consider using **PATCH** as you're **modifying** (resetting and not replacing) existing sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `DELETE @ users/sessions`

If you think about it, a reset is simply an admin dropping a session. The user gets their new session when/if they return. So a reset route does not make much sense as you are not reissuing sessions to all of your users in this action.

My preference is `users/sessions` rather then `users/{*}/sessions`. The later route suggests that you are wanting to remove all sessions of the parent resource, in this case being a single user.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to expose another method for the admin to delete (reset) a user's all sessions. I am considering 2 options, I wonder which one is more Restful....

You probably want to be using [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3).

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.” -- [Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

HTTP DELETE isn't often the right answer

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect. -- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)

HTTP Methods belong to the "transfer documents over a network" domain, not to *your* domain.

REST doesn't actually care about the spelling of the target-uri -- that's part of the point.  General-purpose HTTP components don't assume that the uri has any specific semantics encoded into it.  It is just a opaque identifier.

That means that you can apply whatever URI design heuristics you like.  It's a lot like choosing a name for a variable or a namespace in a general-purpose programming language; the compiler/interpreter don't usual care if the symbol "means" anything or not.  We choose names that make things easier for the *human beings* that interact with the code.

And so it is with URI as well.  You'll probably want to use a spelling that is consistent with other identifiers in your API, so that it looks as though the api were designed by "one mind".

A common approach starts from the notion that a resource is any information that can be named ([Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)).  Therefore, it's our job to first (a) figure out the name of the resource that handles this request, then (b) figure out an identifier that "matches", that name.  Resources are closely analogous to *documents*, so if you can think of the name of the document in which you would write this message, you are a good ways toward figuring out the name (ex: we write expiring sessions into the "security log", or into the "sessions log".  Great, now figure out the corresponding URI.)

If *I* ran the zoo: I imagine that

```
GET /users/{userKey}/sessions
```

would probably return a representation of the users cookie sessions.  Because this representation would be something that changes when we delete all of the users sessions, I would want to post the delete request to this same target URI

```
POST /users/{userKey}/sessions
```

because doing it that way makes the [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) story a bit easier.